# Ruby chomp!.strip! in one line

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table from a website.

```
status = recPage.css("#MainContent_GridView1").css("tr")[line].css("td")[2].text.chomp.strip
```

And I got this error for some of the rows.

> undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

or

> undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

So I thought I could use `chomp!.strip!` to skip the `nil` values. But apparently it won't allow me to put those 2 into one line.

Is there a way to modify this?

Comment: Why would you think that `chomp!.strip!` would guard you against nils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

`status = recPage.css("#MainContent_GridView1").css("tr")[line].css("td")[2].text.chomp.strip rescue ""`

It will set status to `""`;

Answer (score 0):

You're getting these errors because there're nodes with `.text=nil`, also `chomp!` and `strip!` are meant to modify string in-place, not to ignore errors, and they return `nil`.

Best way is to check the presence of text (not oneliner, thought):

```
txt = recPage.css("#MainContent_GridView1").css("tr")[line].css("td")[2].text
txt = txt.chomp.strip if txt
```

In ruby 2.3+ you can use:

```
recPage.css("#MainContent_GridView1").css("tr")[line].css("td")[2].text&.chomp.&strip
```

`rescue ""`-method could lead to errors in the future (if there are some other errors in this line)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it destructively, you can do:

```
...text&.tap(&:chomp!)&.tap(&:strip!)
```

Comment: @mudasobwa I misinterpreted the question. I didn't expect that the original receiver is `nil`.